# How to spread array with functions and call them inside Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, promise

Lets assume I have an array with callable objects inside:

```
const arr = [ obj1, obj2, obj3, ... ]
```

In my case these objects also return promises and are executable via `.doSomething()`, e.g.:

```
arr[0].doSomething()
```

I need to put them all together into `Promise.all()` and I wonder if there is an approach which uses the spread operator `...` ?

Just `Promise.all(arr)` doesn't work because I have to call `doSomething()` on each of the objects. Something like:

```
Promise.all((...arr) => a.doSomething())
```

Comment: You're looking for `map`, not for spread syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spread syntax won't help here.

You need to use `.map()` method to create a new array that contains the result of calling `.doSomething()` on each element in the `arr` array. This new array then should be passed to [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
const transformedArr = arr.map(o => o.doSomething());
Promise.all(transformedArr);
```

or you can do it in one line

```
Promise.all(arr.map(o => o.doSomething()))
```